# Is it possible using python poplib to obtain specific messages only from the inbox and only delete those retrieved?

Tags: python, email, poplib

I couldn't find my exact question so here goes:

I am using the `poplib` module and can successfully retrieve emails from my inbox and delete those read. However, I would like to only retrieve those emails with a specific subject line (so I can filter out spammed or incorrectly sent messages). Upon retrieval I would then like the messages that were retrieved to be deleted.

Is this possible with `poplib` and maybe another module I don't know about?

Comment: I guess you could get the messages that you want and then delete them from the server using their uidl